# Migrar una librería de jquery a react

Tags: jquery, reactjs, clase

Necesito usar la librería jquery.imgareaselect en react, importé jquery:

> import $ from 'jquery',

luego necesitaba usar una clase de esta libreria asi que lo hice de esta forma

```
$('#mi_imagen').imgAreaSelect({

    aspectRatio: '4:3', 
    handles: true
 });

}
```

el problema es que no logro saber como hacer para que me reconozca la clase si es que como tengo que importar esta clase o como lo hago.

Intente dandole la ruta en el index y no la reconoce y tambien importando la libreria

```
import {imgAreaSelect} from '../../js/imgselect/jquery.imgareaselect.js'
```

y luego lo que intente fue:

```
$('#mi_imagen')imgAreaSelect.imgAreaSelect
```

pero por obvias razones esto no funcionó.

Comment: Te recomiendo que edites tu post dando formato a tu código para que sea fácil de leer y también ten en cuenta que usar Jquery con React es mala práctica, deberías evitar usarlos juntos. ¿De casualidad has buscado una librería de React que haga lo que quieres?

Comment: No logré encontrar lo que necesitaba en react, así que tome la decisión de hacerlo con jquery.

Comment: @Mateo y que es lo que estás tratando de hacer con React (que te ha llevado a integrar JQuery)?

Comment: @jecorrales lo que quería hacer era algo con canvas en el que subías una imagen y esta podia ser recortada y editada, algo parecido a como lo hace gmail al subir una imagen de perfil.

Ya lo pude solucionar lo que hice fue llamar jquery desde el index y no tenia que importarlo si lo que lo llamada jquery y listo sin el $

Comment: Aunque es en cierto modo una mala práctica, deberías de responder tu pregunta para darle solución. De pronto otras personas lleguen hasta aquí con tu mismo problema.

Comment: no agregues resuelto al título de tu pregunta, así no funciona la comunidad, quita eso del título y acepta dando clic a la palomita que esta a lado de la respuesta que resolvió tu problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar lo que hice fue llamar jQuery desde el index de react y no tenia que importarlo si no que en vez de llamar $ lo reemplace por jQuery

```
jQuery('#mi_imagen').imgAreaSelect({

    aspectRatio: '4:3', 
    handles: true
 });

}
```